How to avoid overlaying body content when using a fixed navigation bar?
The bslib::page_navbar function has a position parameter that allows us to keep the navigation bar visible when scrolling down (position="fixed-top"). However, as the documentation points out:

Note that using "fixed-top" or "fixed-bottom" will cause the navbar to overlay your body content, unless you add padding, e.g.: tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}")

I am trying to do this, but with limited success. Here is what I tried:
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(lorem) # for mock data
ui <- bslib::page_navbar(
    theme=bslib::bs_theme(version=5), 
    title="Fixed Navbar Demo",
    position="fixed-top",

    # does not work:
    # shiny::tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 170px;}"), 

    # this works, but I may not have a h2 tag at the top:
    shiny::tags$style(type="text/css", "h2 {padding-top: 170px;}"), 

    bslib::nav_panel(
        "Menu Entry",
        shiny::h2("Content"),
        lorem::ipsum(paragraphs=10)
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)

Searching on stackoverflow, I found hints to bslib::bs_add_rules and "affix" but I could not get it working. How to do this?

Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here. Running your code, the navigation bar remains visible when scrolling as desired.

The problem is that the headline "Content" is not fully visible because it overlaps with the navigation bar. The example works, but I feel it is wrong to redefine h2 for the desired behaviour.

@KarstenW. You can use body {padding-top: 170px !important;}.

@Jan Indeed, that works! Thanks! Would you mind to elaborate in an answer why this works?

The issue is that since no padding parameter is passed to page_navbar, this defaults to 0px for body and this overwrites the body {padding-top: 170px;}. Hence, you could force the usage of your value by setting
body {
  padding-top: 170px !important;
}

(Unrelated here, but please wrap styles inside the header argument of page_navbar: header = tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 170px !important;}")), then you avoid a warning).
However, overwriting defaults by !important is usually not the best way to go. A better possibility might be to use the padding parameter of page_navbar, but then you may need to also define the other values (e.g. padding-bottom). Notice that they default to bslib-spacer * 1.5 with bslib-spacer = 1rem. So you could also use something like this:
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(lorem) # for mock data

ui <- bslib::page_navbar(
  theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5), 
  title = "Fixed Navbar Demo",
  position = "fixed-top",
  
  padding = c(170, "1.5rem", "1.5rem", "1.5rem"),
  
  bslib::nav_panel(
    "Menu Entry",
    shiny::h2("Content"),
    lorem::ipsum(paragraphs=10)
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, \(...){})


Thanks for the great solution. I went for the !important option, because I have a nested structure page_navbar(.., navset_tab(..)) and in the padding solution, the padding seems to get passed on to the inner navset_tab.
